# Lda using mallet

Tags: lda, mallet

I run the file simple lda.java and I got 
 exception in thread `"main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at cc.mallet.topics.SimpleLDA.main(SimpleLDA.java:560)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the command line interface without any parameters.

If you look at the source file at https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/topics/SimpleLDA.java, you can see that line 560 is expecting to find that there is a command line argument specifying a file at the first position in the arguments array.

If you need to train a topic model from the command line, there is information here: http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php

The interface you are using is intended as a base for constructing new, custom topic models in Java. Without significant programming experience in Java this will be frustrating and unlikely to succeed.